# Dockerfile COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} not finding the correct source after upgrade to 3.1

Tags: .net-core, dockerfile

I am using Jenkins to build and deploy a .Net Core microservice application.  For each microservice, I am building a docker container.  My dockerfile has the following in it:

> ARG source

> COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .

Prior to upgrading from .Net Core 2.2 to 3.1, this worked.  After the upgrade, when I try to deploy, I am getting the following error:

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder609391151/obj/Docker/publish: no such file or directory
> script returned exit code 1

From what I've read, it looks like .Net Core 2.2 compiled into the /obj/Docker/publish directory, but .Net Core 3.1 compiles into the /bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1 directory, however the source is still pointing to /obj/Docker/publish.  I'm trying to figure out where the source arguement is defined, and how I should change this.

Update:

I decided to leave the source out entirely and hard-code the build path.  I changed the copy line to

> COPY /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/fusion-core/branches/master/workspace/src/CustomerAPI/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1 .

I'm still getting an error when I try to build the docker container that says

> COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder356954794/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/fusion-core/branches/master/workspace/src/CustomerAPI/obj/Release/netcoreapp3.1: no such file or directory
> script returned exit code 1

I'm not sure where the "/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder356954794" is coming from, or why it is appending it to the front of my path, but it doesn't exist.

Still not sure how to get around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some debugging suggestions in no certain order.

### Default Value

`${source:-obj/Docker/publish}` is [bash syntax](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#use_a_default_value) that evaluates to the value of the variable `source` if it was defined, or `obj/Docker/publish` if it was not.

> I'm trying to figure out where the `source` argument is defined, and how I should change this.

If you can't find anything that defines it to another value, it just means that the default value `obj/Docker/publish` was being used.

### Publish directory

3.1 still uses the `publish` directory, but it will be at `bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish`. Use a `RUN find -type d -iname publish` to find the publish directories in your container.

Dont use the full path, it will change every build. See the `tmp/docker-builder356954794` in the path?

The `COPY` command uses relative files, based on the path in your machine (outside the docker container). So use a path that's relative to where the context directory (or `Dockerfile`) is. If the dockerfile is at `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/fusion-core/branches/master/workspace/src/CustomerAPI/Dockerfile` and the publish directory on your machine is at `/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/fusion-core/branches/master/workspace/src/CustomerAPI/bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish`, then use a `COPY` command like this:

```
COPY bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish .
```

### Funny paths

> I'm not sure where the "/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder356954794" is coming from

Containers need to share files from one directory (in your host) to another (in your container). Depending on the container technology, it uses one or more file systems or file directories.

One of those is `/var/lib/docker/tmp/...`

Comment: Well, I can't test this out at the moment, but I'm going to mark your answer as resolving it since you answered my questions and put me on the right track.  Thanks!